# Screen output getting cut-off (using vertical scroll bars) when connected to Ubuntu Server 16.04 via SSH. not a problem with RHEL7

Tags: 16.04, ssh

I believe the issue is best explained using an example:

I ran this command (cat /etc/samba/smb.conf) on 3 servers:

1. server running FreeBSD 10.x (equivalent path as the path is different on FreeBSD)
2. server running RHEL 7 (equivalent path as the path is different on RedHat)
3. server running Ubuntu Server 16.04 (with latest patches)

My smb.conf is easily around 100 lines so I cannot view the output without using "more" command or "scrolling back".

On FreeBSD and RedHat, I can use the vertical scroll bar to easily view the complete file contents without having to use "more".

BUT on Ubuntu, using the vertical scroll bar is useless. I believe this is best explained with a pic.

[image]

As you can see, the login message somehow "covers" the beginnings of my smb.conf. I'm not sure which setting to change so I can have the same behavior like when connected to FreeBSD/RHEL7.

For reference, this is the beginning of my smb.conf

[image]

Any ideas how it can be done? Thanks a lot